# How to open an android activity when I click on a notification

Tags: android

I want open an specific android activity when I click on a notification, but the problem is that when I click on my notifiation this open my MainActivity but for example i want open my activity that is called Notificacion.class, I use a firebase of google and this is my code.

```
public class MyfirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    //final Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notificacion.class);
    //startActivity(intent);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notificacion.class);
    intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Sección 15");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSound);
    long[] pattern = new long[]{1000,500,1000};
    notificationBuilder.setVibrate(pattern);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());


}
```

}

Comment: I have actually tried your code and it showed activity that I wanted. I can give you couple of standard pieces of advice:
 - check manifest if the desired activity is there
 - try to use context.getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intent you create and pass to the pending Intent is the one used when you click the notification so put the Activity you want to open in the intent and you can also add extra data to the intent and retrieve them by getting the intent getIntent()

Comment: yes I know but, 
In my notification class, I have a code that serves with a dialog box, in this box is more detailed information sent by the notification, it is something like a pupup, what I really look for is that by clicking on my notification, I run my application and I display a dialogue box with the complete notification information, that's why I want to send my class Notification.class, I do not want to open the main class

Comment: You should open the launcher activity first then get the intent . If exists
create new intent passing all the data in the old one to it with notification.class as the targeted activity

Comment: Thanks, I'll deal with that solution

Answer (score 1):

Replace "Notificacion.class" for your activity in this line:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notificacion.class);
```

It should looks like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
```

Comment: If the answer is correct please mark it as the correct Answer ! Thanks!

Comment: In my notification class, I have a code that serves with a dialog box, in this box is more detailed information sent by the notification, it is something like a pupup, what I really look for is that by clicking on my notification, I run my application and I display a dialogue box with the complete notification information, that's why I want to send my class Notification.class, I do not want to open the main class

Comment: So, you should open your activity from your dialog. Create a new intent inside your dialog and start the desired activity once the user is ready to go.